# Making a variable from @include

Tags: css, sass

This I hope is a simple question to answer.  I have SASS @include that calculates the size of font dynamical.

```
h2 {
   @include rfs(2rem);
}
```

I use this to "shrink" the size of the font as the screen resolution decreases in size.  The problem is a "grey background" does not auto-adjust with the decreasing font size.

I was thinking if I can somehow make the @include rfs(2rem) into a variable, I could make something like this:

```
$fs: @include rfs(2rem);

.grey-background {
   height: calc( #{$fs} + 3vh );
}
```

I am not sure if I need to make this into a @mixin or if something else...  I just want the grey background to auto-adjust with the adjusting font size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [SASS @function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function):

```
@function rfs($size) {
  @return ...
}

$fs: rfs(2rem);

.grey-background {
   height: calc( #{$fs} + 3vh );
}
```

Comment: Great!  I will look into this.  Thanks!

Comment: Arkelleys..  We went with a different approach for a solution, so I was not able to use your method to see if it worked or not.  Sorry...